# Disable enumeration of properties in JavaScript without ECMAScript 5

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

With ECMAScript 5 we have `Object.defineProperty`, which allows us to describe how a property should respond to some actions. One of the possibilites from this is to disable enumeration of properties, so they won't show up in `for...in` loops. For example the `length` property of arrays is not enumerable.

Is it possible to do something similar without ECMAScript 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possibel to create non-enumerable properties in ECMA-262 ed 3, but you can [emulate private members](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).